# Can I get the enum key from an assigned value when using enum strings?

Tags: typescript

Can I get the enum key from an assigned value when using enum strings - I need to get which key is used, not the string value.

Example:

```
enum Widgets {
   Foo: 'this is foo',
   Bar: 'this is bar'
}

const current = Widgets.foo;
console.info(current); // 'this is foo';

// later on, I need to get the key of the enum used in current i.e. the value 'Foo', not the string value 'this is foo'
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/enum-keys-792le?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get enum key by use

```
let key = Object.keys(Widgets)[Object.values(Widgets).indexOf(current)]
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-av8rkx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't seem to work and would return the value of the enum, not the key surely? I need to return the key name.

Comment: I updated answer